# How to set the height of several buttons in a LinearLayout for Android?

Tags: android

I want to make some buttons on a panel quite thin but have no success. I have tried basically everything and if i manually enter the height of the button in the attribute android:layout_height, the button does not look correct. Everything else I try, the button still remains as large as before.

How can I accomplish this most easily?

```
  <LinearLayout 
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         > 
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 

            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:textSize="3sp"
            android:text="B1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 

            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:textSize="3sp"
            android:text="B2"
            android:onClick="onClick"
         />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Some Android themes use default height in the button view. Have you tested to override the style? Or use the attribute for small buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Use weight in linear layout

```
  <LinearLayout 
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content  weight_sum=10"
     > 
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6" 
        android:textSize="3sp"
        android:text="B1"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4" 
        android:textSize="3sp"
        android:text="B2"
        android:onClick="onClick"
     />


</LinearLayout>
```